# How to detect specific version of RHEL OS in install4j installer

Tags: installation, install4j

We have a installer project written in install4j 6.1. We have a dialog which is to be displayed only if the OS is RHEL 9. Is there a way in the install4j installer to detect whether the system is RHEL 9 or other RHEL version ?

Util.isLinux() only determines whether system is Linux or not. It does not give specific Linux version.

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 10, this is not available. You can parse the contents of the file

```
/etc/os-release
```

to get information about the Linux version.